# Ruby/ROR disable a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

My question is related to ROR, but in fact it's rather about ruby syntax I think.

In a model there is a built in method 'save', which saves the model to a database. I need to override the method, to do some additional job concerning files. I overloaded the method with a new one which takes 2 arguments. What I want to do now is to disable the original save method, so I don't use it somewhere accidentally. For now I managed to do this by using alias_method. Now after calling save method with no arguments only prints a message to the console. The problem is this message probably will be overlooked.

What will be the best way to handle this?
Bye

Comment: Generally it is a bad idea to redefine build-in methods, especially if you change arity. Define your own, or redefine build-in with the same arity if you want to add something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best option is to use the `before_save` and `after_save` callbacks in Ruby on Rails.

You can read more about them here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview

Comment: This is the right way to do it. I would add that if a `before_save` callback returns `false`, then the `save` will be averted.